# Google Maps - Custom Overlay - Software and Process

Tags: google-maps, kml

Looking for some advice on what is used to create an overlay for Google maps that looks like the MIT maps, http://whereis.mit.edu/ ( click on Classic view ), or this map:  http://www.washington.edu/maps/.

We're going to creating some maps for various college campuses and would like to mimic the look of the buildings and points of interest on those types of maps.

Need to figure out what software is typically used to do something like that, and then how to get the overlay stuck onto a custom Google map.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 concepts:

1. **overlays.** You use them to put single images (icons or maps) over the normal map. Use [Ground overlays](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#GroundOverlays) or [Custom overlays](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays) from [Google maps API v3](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) - there is a very good documentation with examples ([ground overlay](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple.html), [custom overlay](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple.html)). Ground overlays seems to be simpler, you just put an image over the map and specify corner coordinates. Custom overlays allow for more functionality, but are more complex to use.
2. layers. I wrote some on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8356767/684229).