# Google Map API 3 + WMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, wms

Can somebody give me best idea, how to put WMS layer over Google map I have so many layers and so many styles. I research on so many Q and A at StackOverflow, but I didn't get the point about how to manage multiple styles and layers. I would like to put into my JQuery code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a great example on this here: http://www.sumbera.com/lab/GoogleV3/tiledWMSoverlayGoogleV3.htm

Here you have 2 kinds of layers:

1. base layer which is in the bottom
2. overlayed semi-transparent layer which is above all other layers

(note: in the above example they use WMS just for case 2, but you can of course use it also for 1, as the interface (object `google.maps.ImageMapType`) is the same for both)

Basically, to add "base layers" you use:

```
map.mapTypes.set('OSM', new google.maps.ImageMapType({ ... }));
```

To add overlayed layer you use:

```
map.overlayMapTypes.push(new google.maps.ImageMapType({ ... }));
```

To add layers to map type control you use option when creating the map:

```
mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: [
        'OSM', 
        google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
        google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, 
        google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, 
        google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    ],
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
}
```

The above example illustrates this greatly. As for the styling of the WMS layers, this is pretty complex, I also put [a question about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8320512/684229). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WMS and Google Maps</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var EXTENT = [-Math.PI * 6378137, Math.PI * 6378137];

      function xyzToBounds(x, y, z) {
        var tileSize = (EXTENT[1] * 2) / Math.pow(2, z);
        var minx = EXTENT[0] + x * tileSize;
        var maxx = EXTENT[0] + (x + 1) * tileSize;
        // remember y origin starts at top
        var miny = EXTENT[1] - (y + 1) * tileSize;
        var maxy = EXTENT[1] - y * tileSize;
        return [minx, miny, maxx, maxy];
      }

      var getTileUrl = function(coordinates, zoom) {
        return (
          "https://www.mrlc.gov/geoserver/NLCD_Land_Cover/wms?" +
          "&REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1" +
          "&LAYERS=mrlc_display%3ANLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48" +
          "&FORMAT=image%2Fpng" +
          "&SRS=EPSG:3857&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256" +
          "&BBOX=" +
          xyzToBounds(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, zoom).join(",")
        );
      };

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: { lat: 37.783, lng: -122.403 }
        });

        var landcover = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
          getTileUrl: getTileUrl,
          name: "Landcover",
          alt: "National Land Cover Database 2016",
          minZoom: 0,
          maxZoom: 19,
          opacity: 0.75,
        });
        map.overlayMapTypes.push(landcover);
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can read the details here: https://justin.poehnelt.com/posts/google-maps-wms-layer/