# WMS (Web Map Service) connector?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, wms

The following site contains a WMS connector? how would i go about using WMS connector to overlay in google maps API?

http://sentinel.ga.gov.au/acres/sentinel/wfs_wms.shtml

Thanks for your time! =)

Edit:

The problem is i am having difficulty understanding how to overlay the WMS connector (found on the provided web site link) onto Google Maps API. When i place WMS connector in my HTML coding, a file of unsupported format is generated for download, instead of showing a map image.

I have no restrictions on how to overlay the WMS onto google API. I just need a way of overlaying a fire-hot spot of Australia WMS over google API for a project. I have started my web page, generating the google API as well as javascript for latitude and longitude generation for user input. I came accross the WMS website link that is provided as it seemed promising, however not understanding how to successfully overlay it onto google maps API.

Comment: Welcome to [so].  Currently, we don't have enough information to answer your question.  What's your particular use case?  How would you like us to overlay it?  Do you have any restrictions on how it's supposed to be done?  Have you started anything yet?  That's the type of information that we need to answer your question - it'd be great if you could edit your question to add these sorts of thing in.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi =) the problem is i am having difficulting understanding how to overlay this among google maps API. I have no restrictions on how it is suppose to be done. I just need a way of overlaying a fire-hot spot WMS over google API for a project. I have started my web page, generating the google API as well as javascript for latitude and longitude generation for user input. I came accross the website link that is provided as it seemed promising, however not understanding how to successfully overlay it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map API 3 + WMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354163/google-map-api-3-wms)

Comment: [This](https://wiki.state.ma.us/confluence/display/massgis/Google+Maps+-+Version+3) might also help.  From [this search on google](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=google+maps+api+v3+WMS+services.#q=google+maps+api+v3+WMS+services.)