# arcGIS to google map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, arcgis

my client has ArcGIS installed on his PC
and he has designed roads, hospitals, houses, and parks of a specific area in ArcGIS
he needs his system online.

challenging task for me is how can I get all drawing information from his ArcGIS that I can show    that same drawing on google map using javascript or php or whatever
I searched it but I am not satisfied yet.

there is also a solution of creating ArcGIS Server, but that will be my 2nd priority.
I am thinking to somehow export all drawing information from ArcGIS and feed it to google map.
bcz there will be no frequent changes in drawing he has. (means drawings are static and not changing frequently.)

Comment: You might want to ask this on http://gis.stackexcahnge.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your shapefiles or feature classes to KML:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004n000000

Then use the resulting KML in a Google Map application:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

You should also look into ArcGIS Online.  You can use the same KML, shapefiles or csv files to display your data over some nice basemaps.
http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

Upload your data in a PostGIS and serve this data from a GeoServer, then you can use the WMS layers in your Google Maps application. 
[Google Map API 3 + WMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354163/google-map-api-3-wms)

Periodically exports your data to GeoJSON to adds it as a data layer in your application. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer

Periodically exports your data to KML and adds it as a KMLLayer in your application. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

Answer (score 0):

You can use FME Desktop which is super easy. You need to convert the data to KML. If you dont have FME, you can download free trail from safe software website. Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

Piling on to the KML answer, ArcGIS 10.x should support direct exports to KML.  If this works you can use model builder to save the process and then either set a reminder to periodically run it or automate it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest way to do this is to export your information to KML or KMZ then overlay it onto a google map of your choice.

If you need the ability to have data rich maps and features and don't want to shell out the money for the ArcGIS Platform, look into the OpenGeo suite. I think open Geo is still free but it has been around 3 years since I have used it.

Also a good alternative to ArcMap is QGIS. Just in case you might need to edit map layers and such.